# how to add cocos2d together with AFNetworking in Xcode

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, afnetworking

My project start with cocos2d v3 and run smooth. However, when I  add AFNetworking to my project, 
the problem
"ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" happen.

I used pod install and pod file is
platform :ios, ‘7.0’
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'

during the installing, below messages show out
[!] The `abc [Debug]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

[!] The `abc [Release]` target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

so I go to project->target->build setting-> header search paths and put $(inherited) inside, then it can install success.

However, the cocos2d library wasn't call. So I go to Pods.debug.xcconfig and Pods.release.xcconfig to **add** 
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/AFNetworking" **"$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Libraries/kazmath/include" "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Libraries/Chipmunk/chipmunk/include" "$(SRCROOT)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Libraries/Chipmunk/objectivec/include"**

finally the problem "ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" still happen.

Are the above steps not correct? Or is there any other way to add cocos2d and AFNetworking together? Thank you.

Comment: Do you open the procext via the generated .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproj that you used before?

Comment: Yes, I open the xcworkspace

Comment: Find out the solution, Don't use the pod install, just download the library and put it to the project.